# Which one is correct between these two?

Tags: sentence, syntactic-analysis

Would you say "He is a master of French and Italian cuisine" or "He is a master of both French and Italian cuisine" ? Thanks

Comment: "Cuisines" could be plural (unless you meant French language and Italian cuisine).  The singular only works because 'cuisine' can be a non-count noun.

Answer (score 1):

You can say either. You could use 'both' if you wanted to draw particular attention to the fact that he is a master of more than one type of cuisine.

> both...and...
>
> Usage note
>
> **used for emphasizing that each of two things is true**:
>
> a plant that grows in both Chile and Argentina
>
> The results of the research are both impressive and alarming.
>
> Both she and her sister now live in New Orleans.

[Both...and...(Macmillan Dictionary)](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/both-and)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is correct answer.
He is a master of French and Italian cuisine

Comment: Why do you think that? Good answers help the asker understand the situation but you've just given your opinion, with no indication of why you think this is the correct answer or, more importantly, why anyone else might think that.